# JSX inputbox is deleting and re typing characters rapidly? (video included)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbCsRJd27Nw

This happens after typing a random number of characters. The number of characters it deletes and retypes seems to be random too.

here's the input element:

```
<input  
    value={textInput}   
    onChange={storeInputText}   
    onKeyDown={inputEnterHandler}   
    placeholder='change coin...' 
/>
```

Here's the onChange function:

```
storeInputText = e => {     
    const currentState = { ...this.state };     
    currentState.textInput = e.target.value;
    this.setState(currentState); 
};
```

I'm trying to make an input that shows filtered results below it. If the user clicks on one of the suggestions, I want the value to be set to that. Where did I mess up?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, we'd need more context. Preferably a sandbox recreating the issue

Comment: Why do you override full state object? I assume there is one more state key causing re-render. Try 
`storeInputText = e => this.setState({ storeInputText: e.target.value }); 
`